# How to pass an Activity instance to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

Hi I have an activity named **BaseActivity**, which extends Activity.
from this i have to go to **SettingsActivity** which extends `PreferenceActivity`, on menu button press. To start a `AsyncTask`, which is in an independent class, i need an instance of `BaseActivity`. How can i get a `BaseActivity` instance in the `SettingsActivity`?

is there any way like,
eg:

```
intent.putExtra("activity_instance",BaseActivity.this);
```

Comment: android would not allow to use 
 intent.putExtra("activity_instance",BaseActivity.this); what i am expecting is sending instance of activity some where around calling startActivity

Comment: look at the docs to know the reason http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html the `puExtra` methonds

Comment: what will you do with BaseActivity instance?

Comment: i have a common class 'MyAsyncTasks' which receives BaseActivity instance. and that will do all asynctasks for my entire application. Also 'MyAsyncTasks' have to use methods defined in BaseActivity. My all other activites except one(SettingsActivity) extends BaseActivity. so from other cases i have to pass only the current activity context.  SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity, so when i am sending current activity context a type mis match occurring.

Comment: You can pass data from an activity to another using intent.putExtra("keyvalue", dataHere); .. After you can get this data from another activity ,  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  String yourData = extras.get***("keyvalues");   *** means type of your data.

Comment: @ArunWarrier you can use Activity extends BaseActivity with PreferenceFragment.

Comment: @ArunWarrier:Try to use singleton class approach .Its a good way to do this.i know every one feel lazy to do this.but its upto you..whether you choose singleton or static.but after at one stage you will find that static is bad idea as we dont know when it will be garbage collected.

Comment: @all : i am using singleton class approach, its working for me , thank you all for your valuable answers. !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use getters and setters and make the class they reside as singleton class.**

**This is a singleton class.Using this class we can share data(ex: int,boolean,activity instance ...etc) all over the class**.

```
public class CommonModelClass 
{
    public static CommonModelClass singletonObject;
    /** A private Constructor prevents any other class from instantiating. */

  private Activity baseActivity; 

    public CommonModelClass() 
    {
        //   Optional Code
    }
    public static synchronized CommonModelClass getSingletonObject() 
    {
        if (singletonObject == null) 
        {
            singletonObject = new CommonModelClass();
        }
        return singletonObject;
    }


    /**
     * used to clear CommonModelClass(SingletonClass) Memory
     */ 
     public void clear()  
      {  
         singletonObject = null;  
      }


    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException 
    {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
    }

    //getters and setters starts from here.it is used to set and get a value

    public Activity getbaseActivity()
    {
        return baseActivity;
    }

    public void setbaseActivity(Activity baseActivity)
    {
        this.baseActivity = baseActivity;
    }   

}
```

In BaseActivity class do like this.

```
         Class BaseActivity extends Activity{


                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    CommonModelClass commonModelClass = CommonModelClass.getSingletonObject();

    commonModelClass.setbaseActivity(BaseActivity.this);

//after using the BaseActivity instance dont forget to call commonModelClass.clear(); else it wont be garbage collected         


               }

            }
```

In SettingsActivity do like this

```
 Class SettingsActivity extends Activity{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            CommonModelClass commonModelClass = CommonModelClass.getSingletonObject();



            Activity instanceBaseActivity=  commonModelClass.getbaseActivity();;


       }

    }
```

please give tick if this works

Comment: i feel using singleton class is the good approach among all. I am using this option and it is working for me. !!

Comment: That's great.If you want to clear(make the instance null) singleton class value's use commonModelClass.clear(); .so that your code will be more efficient(all the reference that the singleton class holds will be garbage collected).But make sure that you call this method only when all your job done else you will lose your value.

Comment: Hey, nice. I looked for hours to call main functionality in my helper class - now it WORKS great - Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing activities with class objects. The moment activity class is instantiated it obeys all activity life cycle rules, importantly system can kill this activity any time. So you have to design activities in such a way that it shouldn't be dependent on another activity instance at all but only drive the results. you can write a helper class and call it again and again if you want. if not use storages like sdcard or preference or sandbox to store the information and retrieve it from the other activity. If you want to keep some of these information in memory then subclass Application class and keep them at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

Make a static Context in "Base Activity"

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{
     public static Context ctxt;
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      ctxt  = BaseActivity.this
    }
}
```

and in your "PreferenceActivity" activity use this way

```
BaseActivity.ctxt
```

Comment: not working. throws a error "Cannot use 'this' in a static context"