# Returning data to the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view and from this recyclerview onclick an item it goes to another activity passing the recycler view title and notes. In that activity I can edit the title but how do I sent back the edition to the recycler view ?

Should I override onStop and place there a method to pass the data ? But how do I pass this data ? Do I do an intent or is there a better way to pass this data with good performance ? And later I should call a notifyitemchanged ?

I really appreciate any help or suggestions you can provide

Edit : Some code :

How I pass the data

```
fun AnotherActivityOpen(coisa: ClasseP) {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("nome", coisa.nome)
        bundle.putString("notas", coisa.notas)

        val intent = Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtras(bundle)
        this.startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Edit 2: The data is in a list in the adapter but I also save it in a sqlite database.

Edit 3: more code, the app is very big for now ill put the code that is needed right ?

```
class AnotherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_another)

        titulo.setText(intent.getStringExtra("nome"))
        notas.setText(intent.getStringExtra("notas"))
```

Comment: from where you are getting data ?

Comment: post some code.

Comment: and when data is edited, so you update it also on the server

Comment: From the adapter recycler view list through a bundle in the intent.

Comment: great, so when user is done with changes, so do you update your data on server
like name was ASDF and then user changed that to ASD so do you also update data on server ?

Comment: No its on sqlite. I update with some code

Comment: so means data is updated, so what is the issue, Get data from your sqilte db in onResume

Comment: and notify the adapter

Comment: post your all code

Comment: Ahh got it so I save it on the Sqlite db an load it into the recycler view from the database ? I where thinking about sending it back through a bundle or something. I still have to pass an id or something to find the item in the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Create `OnItemChangeListner` interface:

```
public interface OnItemChangeListner{
   public void onItemChanged(int position, String newTitle, String newNote);
}
```

Assuming the first activity contains a recyclerView and an array that stores items.

> FirstActivity.java

```
class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnItemChangeListner{
     RecyclerView rcvList;
     ArrayList<Item> items;
     YourRecyclerView adapter;
     //...some methods 
     @Override
     public void onItemChanged(int position, String newTitle, String newNote){
        items.get(position).setTitle(newTitle);
        items.get(position).setNote(newNote);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
}
```

> SecondActivity.java

```
class public SecondActivity extends Activity{
        OnItemChangeListner listener;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             CommonModelClass commonModelClass = CommonModelClass.getSingletonObject();

             Activity firstActivity=  commonModelClass.getbaseActivity();;
             listener = (OnItemChangeListener)firstActivity;
             submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view){
                     listener.onItemChanged(position,newTitle,newNote);
                 }
             });
        }
}
```

What is CommonModelClass??? Please see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21773074/8531215